# Using a pull-up resistor and considering rise time for IC input

Tags: pcb-design, fpga, pullup, signal-integrity, rise-time

I have a FPGA based design in which the FPGA is interfaced with several ICs. The I/Os of the FPGA and most of the ICs are 3.3V, except from one where the I/Os are 1.8V. While there is no problem for the outputs of the IC to the FPGA, which supports 1.8V inputs, the opposite is not possible since all the banks are configured with 3.3V (and dedicating a bank to 1.8V sky rockets the PCB design complexity).

The inputs of that IC are not 3.3V tolerant, so I am trying to find a way to communicate without a violation. One solution I have come up with is using pull-up R's to 1.8V and open-drain outputs of the FPGA.

According to the IC datasheet, the rise time (20% to 80%) of the inputs should be up to 5ns. The trace length from the FPGA to the IC is a little less than 50 mm. By entering the PCB and trace properties to the Saturn PCB, under Conductor Impedance tab, it is estimated that the capacitance of the conductor is 0.873 pF/cm. Multiplying the length of the conductor with its capacitance per cm yields a total capacitance of 4.37 pF. Assuming a typical 3 pF input pin capacitance of the IC, the total capacitance is 7.37 pF.

According to [Wiki RC Constant article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_time_constant), you can calculate tr using RC time constant, and the equation is tr=1.4τ . By targeting a 4ns rise time and solving the equation for R, the result is R=387 Ohm.

Based on the above, a standard 360 Ohm resistor can be used as a pullup in order to provide a proper rise time. Additionally, for 1.8V and 360 Ohm resistance the current will be 5 mA, which is within the current sink capabillity of the FPGA per pin.

Is my reasoning correct or have I missed anything?

I prefer to use that method over a dedicated level translator due to much lower cost and ease of implementation in the design (the PCB is really small). Also, there are only two inputs for that IC (three actually, but the one is high almost all the time), so the additional 10 mA of consumption is acceptable.

Comment: Not an answer to your question RE rise time, but If you have a 1.8V supply to hand, I would consider using a level shifter IC, even something as simple as SN74LV1T34 would work wonders.

Comment: And those T34 gates are available as dual too, maybe even triple or quad. No reason to resort to RC tricks if the signal rise time is important.

Comment: Or just use a buffer that is not labelled as "level shifter" but has overvoltage-tolerant inputs, i.e., anything in the AUC/AUP/LVC logic families.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations. I considered them but, unfortunately, I cannot use them. The reason is that the 1.8V power rail is driven by a LDO. When the specific IC (and functional block of the PCB) is not used, the power (LDO) is disabled. Almost all buffers require a VCC (I think only one accepted 0V in recommended operation conditions - the LDO output has a strong pull down when disabled) and I am only left with the option of using an open drain buffer, which is what I already have. Hence, if not what I described, I have to use a "proper" level shifter- which I try to avoid.